# Creating two arrays from variable in javascript

Tags: javascript

In this function, variable midArc stores positive and negative numbers. How can these values be used to create two new arrays, one containing positive values and another one containing negative values?

```
function cosVal(){
    var val = [2,5,7,6,9];
    for(i=0; i<val.length; i++){
        var midArc = Math.cos(val[i]);
        alert(midArc); //displays 3 positive and 2 negative numbers 
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just check whether or not the number is greater or less than zero:

```
function cosVal(){
    var val = [2,5,7,6,9], positives = [], negatives = [];
    for(i=0; i<val.length; i++){
        var midArc = Math.cos(val[i]);
        (midArc >= 0) ? positives.push(midArc) : negatives.push(midArc);
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a possible solution: It pushes negative numbers to one array, and positive numbers (and zero) to another array.

```
function cosVal(){
    var aryNeg=[];
    var aryPos=[];
    var val = [2,5,7,6,9];
    for(i=0; i<val.length; i++){
        var midArc = Math.cos(val[i]);
        if(midArc<0){
            aryNeg.push(midArc);
        }else{
            aryPos.push(midArc);
        }
        alert(midArc); //displays 3 positive and 2 negative numbers 
    }   
}
```